# Permanently delete data from SQL server database

Tags: sql-server-2012, truncate, truncate-log

I am currently working on a WinForm application with SQL Server Express 2012 and entity framework 6.
Now my Client want the option of deleting all the data from the database upon his request.
I read many articles online which say that data can we recovered even from truncated tables using transaction log and some paid tools. 
But I want,complete removal of data from database such that it can not be recovered by any means and restore it from last taken backup manually after sometime.

So my query is how delete selected table data from sql server database permanently.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd408732.aspx

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/319129/how-to-permanently-delete-data-off-windows-2003-server